# Java Nested ArrayList not Adding Correctly

Tags: java

I have been trying out nested arrayList methods. I have a problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> subList = new ArrayList<Integer>(){{
        add(1);
        add(2);
    }};
    list.add(subList);
    subList.clear();
    subList.add(3);
    subList.add(4);
    list.add(subList);
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

This does not give expected output. The result is

```
[[3, 4], [3, 4]]
```

and not `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`

What is wrong with my Code.

EDIT: I have a few more issues on the code. Should I create a new quetsion or add it here.

Comment: Please add the proper tag.

Comment: You are adding just a reference of sublist to list. You need to create a new sublist instead of clearing the old one.

Comment: What you have created: `list = [ sublist, sublist ]` Note that you have only one sublist with two references to it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would advice you against using double brace initialization `new ArrayList<Integer>{{ }}` as it is kind of an anti-pattern and also creates anonymous inner classes.

As for the error, you should initialize a new list instead of `clear()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> subList = new ArrayList<>();
    subList.add(1);
    subList.add(2);
    list.add(subList);
    subList = new ArrayList<>();
    subList.add(3);
    subList.add(4);
    list.add(subList);
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Calling clear does not change the reference to the ArrayList, and will point to the same object. You should create a new reference by calling `subList = new ArrayList<>()`

A good read about the ill-effects of double brace initialization

https://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/08/dont-be-clever-the-double-curly-braces-anti-pattern/

EDIT: As @NoDataFound suggests, if you are using Java 8+, the process of creating a List can be much more simplified.

If you are using Java 8, you can create a list by using

```
List<Integer> subList = Arrays.asList(1, 2);
```

If you are using Java 9+, you can make use of

```
List<Integer> subList = List.of(1, 2);
```

Comment: I couldn't agree more about the double-brace approach.  People who use it generally do not understand what it really means, because people who *do* understand what it really means generally avoid it.  It is an abomination.  And of course you're right about the nature of the OP's problem, too.

Comment: You should add that calling `new ArrayList + add` can be totally replaced by `Arrays.asList(1, 2)` and `Arrays.asList(3, 4)`, or in Java 9++, `List.of(1, 2)` and `List.of(3, 4)`.

Comment: Yes @JohnBollinger. That's why I thought I should add that point too, even though it seems unrelated to the actual problem.

Comment: @NoDataFound True. Will add.

Comment: tysm @BlackPearl..!